# CMake Universal Binary - arch depending compile options

Tags: cmake, universal-binary

I'm building a MacOS Universal Binary using `set (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES arm64 x86_64)` - working fine so far.

But x86_64 should have other compile options than arm64.

Is there something like:

```
if (CURRENT_TARGET MATCHES x86_64)
    add_compile_options (-Wall -Ofast -ffast-math -fno-exceptions)
else()
    add_compile_options (-Wall -O3 -fno-exceptions)
endif()
```

Or any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_*` property, though this will unfortunately tie your project to XCode.
If you have a target `my_target` to which you'd like to add multi-arch-specific flags, you would write:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(example)

add_executable(my_target main.cpp)
set_target_properties(
  my_target
  PROPERTIES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_PER_ARCH_CFLAGS_x86_64 "-DBUILDING_FOR_X86_64"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_PER_ARCH_CFLAGS_arm64 "-DBUILDING_FOR_ARM64"
)
```

Then you would build with:

```
$ cmake -G Xcode -S . -B build -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="arm64;x86_64"
$ cmake --build build --config Release
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix flags for a specific architecture with `-Xarch_arm64` or `-Xarch_x86_64`. Your example would be:

```
add_compile_options (-Wall -Xarch_arm64 -O3 -Xarch_x86_64 -Ofast -Xarch_x86_64 -ffast-math -fno-exceptions)
```

Comment: Yeah, works for me too. This is exactly the information I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add [arch=x] to the end of any property to give it architecture specific settings. The formatting that worked for me was:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES
            XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_OTHER_LDFLAGS[arch=x86_64] "${IPP_LIB_DIR}/libippi.a $(inherited)"
            XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_OTHER_LDFLAGS[arch=arm64] "-framework Accelerate $(inherited)")
```

Note that without `$(inherited)`, this will overwrite the non-architecture specific build settings. So in the above example, without `$(inherited)`, libraries added with target_link_libraries() would not be linked.